# mapseasy.com embed google maps with multiple locations

Tags: javascript, google-maps, maps

I was successful embedding google maps api with "mapseasy.com" script.

But their generator only has information for one location... I will need to use this map and have multiple locations.

Notice:
http://mesgolf.com/course-flyover.php

I would like to add another PIN... anyone know how to accomplish this?

Current JS is:

```
function LoadGmaps() {


    var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(40.6094825,-73.7280392);
    var myOptions = {
        zoom: 10,
        center: myLatlng,
        disableDefaultUI: true,
        navigationControl: false,

        mapTypeControl: false,
        streetViewControl: false,
        mapTypeId: google.maps.MapTypeId.ROADMAP
        }
    var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("MyGmaps"), myOptions);
    var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
        position: myLatlng,
        map: map,
        title:"Lawrence Yacht & Country Club"
    });
    var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
        content: "<strong>Lawrence Yacht & Country Club</strong><br /><a href=\"https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7u5kICTb1Qs\" target=\"_blank\" style=\"text-decoration:underline; color:#2a5b2a;\">View Course Flyover</a><br /><br />"
        });
        google.maps.event.addListener(marker, "click", function() {
            infowindow.open(map, marker);
        });


}
```

I will give another long/lat example of a location: 40.65063,-73.528508

The HTML looks like this:

```
<div id="MyGmaps" style="width:100%;height:100%; position:absolute;"></div>
```

Comment: Have you tried just adding another marker to that code? What problems did you encounter?

Comment: That probably would work.. I tried but not the best with js... I tried to my a jfiddle but nothing is showing up...http://jsfiddle.net/3nNtN/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See the [documentation of the Google Maps Javascript API v3 on Markers](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/markers)

```
var marker2 = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: new google.maps.LatLng(40.65063,-73.528508),
    map: map,
    title:"marker 2"
});
var infowindow2 = new google.maps.InfoWindow({
    content: "<strong>Marker 2</strong><br />more information<br /><br />"
    });
    google.maps.event.addListener(marker2, "click", function() {
        infowindow2.open(map, marker2);
    });
```

[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/tmL8m/)

Comment: That worked.. I tried something similar myself but I must have had a typo